# how to crop image using yolo format image coordinate

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, crop, yolo

Greeting stackoverflow community,
I have 200 images with labelled `txt` file for `yolo` custom model.
Now I want to crop all the heads present in those images using `txt` coordinate.
I have tried with `opencv`.
But I am getting error.
Could you please help me to crop all the heads of those images automatically?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

Please see the update code :

```py
import cv2

img = cv2.imread(<image path>)

dh, dw, _ = img.shape
print(dh,dw)

x,y,w,h = 0.360667, 0.089000, 0.113333, 0.130000

x,y,w,h = int(x*dw), int(y*dh), int(w*dw), int(h*dh)

print(x, y, w, h)

imgCrop = img[y:y+h,x:x+w]


cv2.imshow("Crop Image",imgCrop)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```

For better understanding the problem, please see these images :

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

[image: img5]

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors!

Comment: Those coordinates you have do not look like they support x,y,w,h (w and h are not consistent). They are likely the top left and bottom right coordinates as fractions of the actual dimensions (guess?). So multiply them by the width and height of the image and then get the w and h of the crop as the difference in these two corners.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Resource: https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet
# <x_center> <y_center> <width> <height> - float values relative to width and height of image,
# it can be equal from (0.0 to 1.0]
# <x> = <absolute_x> / <image_width>
# <height> = <absolute_height> / <image_height>
# attention: <x_center> <y_center> - are center of rectangle (are not top-left corner)

box = "1 0.615234 0.254688 0.148438 0.178125"
class_id, x_center, y_center, w, h = box.strip().split()
x_center, y_center, w, h = float(x_center), float(y_center), float(w), float(h)
x_center = round(x_center * dw)
y_center = round(y_center * dh)
w = round(w * dw)
h = round(h * dh)
x = round(x_center - w / 2)
y = round(y_center - h / 2)

imgCrop = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to convert those float values to integers. You would do this by multiplying them by the width and height of the image then casting them to ints.

Example:

```
x,y,h,w = int(x*img_width), int(y*img_height), int(h*img_higth), int(w*img_width)
```

Then index the image:

```
imgCrop = img[x:x+w, y:y+h]
```

Comment: Try `img[y:y+h,x:x+w]`. I reversed the indices.

Comment: Mr. @belfner sorry to say you. I have tried all of your method. but can't find the exact error. I have updated the question above. Could you please see the last section and img3, img4 and img5 and tell me where is  the actual problem?